# Is possible to use Entity Framework 4 to call procs without mapping to the DB?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I am using Visual 2010 with store procedures. I see all examples of EF involve mapping to the DB. Can I call them without mapping? We are creating a ton new procs though out the week...its would be alot of work/coordination to update the mapping though out the development. I was thinking of using Enterprise library instead?

Comment: It depends.. What kind of sprocs are they?  If they scalar, insert one piece of data or retrieve one piece of data, then its relatively easy.  If you need to map it to objects, then you need to create mappings.

Comment: The CRUD procs: Delete, Update, Select, Insert

Comment: My goal is to cut back on writing a ton of ADO.net to call procs and map results to my entities/models.

Comment: why the heck do you need stored procs for CRUD?  That's a perfect use for EF.

Comment: I heard this argument before and totally get it. It just easier for 2 developers to separate the work...I work on UI and the other focuses on db/procs and getting the data...The updatingthe mapping and keeping everything in sync is the issue with a constantly changing db

Comment: But if you're doing CRUD, then you can use scaffolding to generate the updates, you don't need someone to write any stored procs... it gets done for you... Unless you have other logic, in which case it's no longer CRUD

Comment: You make good points..need to rethink it

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string connectionString = (myObjectContext.Connection as System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC Sp_MyStoredProcedure @param1, @param2", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", param1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", param2));
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What part of that uses entity framework?  Other than getting a connection string?

Comment: Basically I want to do this:

Comment: using (var entity = new FunctionsContext())
{
    var Parameter = new SqlParameter {
                     ParameterName = "FunctionId",
                     Value = 5
            };

    var DBdata = entity.Database.SqlQuery<Course>("exec GetFunctionByID @FunctionId ", Parameter).ToList<Functions>();
}

Comment: Map my results to my entity and cutting back on writing ado.net like your example?

Comment: Your question was: Can I call them without mapping? This example is a workaround, how to call them without mapping. Finally, if you want to map results from stored procedures to your entities there is two ways: 1. update your storage model and mapping content with complex types in .edmx or 2. use my workaround and map the result ds to your entity. The question is how many stored procedures you have and what way is less difficult for you?